# Properly formating a crontab executable on a bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I’m having some serious issues with trying to get the proper format for my bash script to be able to run successfully in crontab. The bash script runs successfully when manually prompted from the command line. 
Here is the bash script in question (the actual parameters themselves [$1 & $2] have been manually placed in the script):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./s3DeleteByDateVirginia "bucketname" "file type"

past=$(date +"%F" -d "60 days ago")

aws s3api list-objects --bucket $1 --query 'Contents[?LastModified<=`'$past'`][].{Key:Key}' | grep $2 | while read -r line
do
fileName=`echo $line`
aws s3api delete-object  --bucket $1 --key "$fileName"
done;
```

The script is in this bash file: /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1
To set up the script I use: sudo crontab –e
Now I see people online saying you need to give it the proper path which doesn’t make any sense to me especially when it comes to putting it in the right location because I’m seeing a number of various modifications of this online but it consists of this format: SHELL=/bin/sh sPATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin but I don't know where to put it.

According to the syslog the cron functionalities that parts working but the script itself doesn’t execute:[image: syslog]

In addition to this the script has all of the proper permissions to run.
All in all, I’m more confused that when I started and I’m not seeing that much documentation on how crontab works.

Crontab in question: [image]

Additional Edits based on user's suggestions:
  Here's my polished script:
[image]

Here's the crontab line:

```
 # m h  dom mon dow   command

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/root/.local/bin/aws
33 20 * * *  /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateSoco1
```

Updated syslog: 
[image]

Comment: The `cron` should generate a message in `/var/mail/root`  To make it easy .. empty that file, then run the `cron` and view the inputs ..  There should be some useful information as far as troubleshooting ...

Comment: Does the script work correctly when you run `bash -c "/home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1"` from your terminal?

Comment: You don't need to run "bash -c".  Instead, make your script executable via "chmod +x FILE" and then try running your script directly.  It will use bash because of the first line in the header.  Change the line in the crontab file with the full path of the file but no call to bash.

Comment: The script works when I input it from the command line as:   ./s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1    . It doesn't work with the bash -c format. That's just me trying anything to try and get it to work. The syslog shows that a little better. @CharlieHileman

Comment: @thatotherguy Post above this

Comment: @Zak How do I view the logs in that file? I tried using tail /var/mail/root and it just gave me the security warning error from when I tried to access  it as a non root user.

Comment: Just use `vim` or `nano` AFTER the `cron` runs .. Like I said just empty the file ..  then run the `cron`  -- Then `sudo vi /var/mail/root/`  and view the message ..  `tail` might not work in this case ..

Comment: In addition ..  You're running `sudo crontab –e`  --  But when you "run" your script manually are you using `sudo`?    Each `user` (including `root`) has their own `crontab`  .. And these users need permissions to access the various parts of the script they are trying to execute ..

Comment: @Zak In regards to your second comment, that's actually something I hadn't considered or even heard of.

Comment: @Zak Okay I did what you said for the mail root. Here's the errors that it prompted and the associated commands with each: 
 |  root -l /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1.sh
/bin/sh: 1: root: not found


|  root -l /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1
/bin/sh: 1: root: not found


 | root /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1
/bin/sh: 1: root: not found

Comment: @Zak root /bin/bash /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1.sh
/bin/sh: 1: root: not found

| bash -c "/home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1.sh"
bash: /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1.sh: No such file or directory


| /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1.sh
/bin/bash: /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1.sh: No such file or directory

| /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1.sh
/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1.sh: not found


/home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1
/home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1: line 6: aws: command not found

Comment: @Zak Okay so you're onto something here. The script doesn't work when I run it from the command line as root user!

Comment: What about if you put the cron into just `crontab -e` without the `sudo`

Comment: @Zak It doesn't run when it's not in super user.

Comment: Confusing! 3 remarks of you:
`The bash script runs successfully when manually prompted from the command line.`,
`The script doesn't work when I run it from the command line as root user!` and
`It doesn't run when it's not in super user.`.

Comment: @WalterA Yes allow me to clarify. I was attempting to run the script in super user from the command line and it wouldn't work. The issue was that I didn't have the AWS CLI installed on SU. Now when it comes to crontab itself, it appears to only run scripts in SU but won't run them as a regular user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I see several problems here. First, you need to put this in the crontab file for the user you want the script to run as. If you want to run it under your user account, do not use just `crontab -e` instead of `sudo crontab -e` (with `sudo`, it edits the root user's crontab file).

Second, you need to use the correct path & name for the script; it looks like it's `/home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1`, so that's what should be in the crontab entry. Don't add ".sh" if it's not actually part of the filename. It also looks like you tried adding "root" in front of the path; don't do that either, since crontab will try to execute "root" as a command, and it'll fail. `bash -c` doesn't hurt, but it doesn't help at all either, so don't use it.

Third, the PATH needs to be set appropriately for the executables you use in the script. By default, cron jobs execute with a PATH of just "/usr/bin:/bin", so when you use a command like `aws`, it'll look for it as `/usr/bin/aws`, not find it, look for it as `/usr/aws`, not find it, and give the error "aws: command not found" that you see in the last log entry. First, you need to find out where `aws` (and any other programs your script depends on) are; you can use `which aws` in your regular shell to find this out. Suppose it's /usr/local/bin/aws. Then you can either:

- Add a line like `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` (with maybe any other directories you think are appropriate) to the crontab file, *before* the line that says to run your script.
- Add a line like `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` (with maybe any other directories you think are appropriate) to the your script file, *before* the lines that use `aws`.
- In your script, use an explicit path every time you want to run `aws` (something like `/usr/local/bin/aws s3api list-objects ...`)

You can use any (or all) of the above, but you must use at least one or it won't be able to find the `aws` command (or anything else that isn't in the set of core commands that come with the OS).

Fourth, I don't see where `$1` and `$2` are supplied. You say they've been manually placed in the script, but I don't know what you mean by that. Since the script expects them as parameters, you need to specify them in the crontab file (i.e. the command in crontab should be something like `/home/ubuntu/s3DeleteByDateVirginiaSoco1 bucketname pattern`).

Fifth, the script itself doesn't follow good quoting conventions. In general, all variable references should be in double-quotes. For example, use `grep "$2"` instead of `grep $2`. Without the double-quotes, variables that contain spaces or certain shell metacharacters can cause weird parsing problems.

Finally, why do you do `fileName=echo $line` (with backquotes I can't replicate here)? This mostly just copies the value of `$line` into the variable `fileName`, but can have those weird parsing problems I mentioned in the last point. If you want to copy a variable reliably, just use `fileName="$line"` (or `fileName=$line` -- this is one of the few cases where it's safe to leave the double-quotes off).

BTW, [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common problems like bad quoting; I recommend running your scripts through it to see what it finds.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for such a detailed explanation on everything and how it works as well as the advice on how to polish my script. Above I have edited my original to include my updated script, errors and syslog information. It's just giving me the classic, "unable to resolve host error."

Comment: `Unable to resolve host` can be caused by an incorrect aws-environment. Perhaps you have some settings (PATH, variables) set in `.bashrc` or `.profile`, these are not read when started from `cron`.

Comment: You can skip `fileName="$line"` when you call the variable fileName in `read -r ..` of when you yse `${line}` in `--key "..."`

Comment: @WalterA is probably right about the incorrect aws-environment. cron jobs run with a really minimal environment, and skip pretty much all of the normal shell setup process, so you need to figure out what the other relevant dependencies are (I don't know aws well enough to help here), and set them up explicitly in the script.